# Collecting Summary Statistics on Dataframe built by randomly sampling other dataframes

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dictionary

My goal is to build a dataframe by randomly sampling from other dataframes, collecting summary statistics on the new dataframe, and then append those statistics to a list. Ideally, I can iterate through this process n number of times (e.g. bootstrap).

```
dfposlist = [OFdf, Firstdf, Seconddf, Thirddf, CFdf, RFdf, Cdf, SSdf]

OFdf.head()
    playerID    OPW         POS salary
87  bondsba01   62.061290   OF  8541667
785 ramirma02   35.785630   OF  13050000
966 walkela01   30.644305   OF  6050000
859 sheffga01   29.090699   OF  9916667
357 gilesbr02   28.160054   OF  7666666
```

All the dataframes in the list have the same headers. What I'm trying to do looks something like this:

```
teamdist = []
for df in dfposlist:
    frames = [df.sample(n=1)]
team = pd.concat(frames)

teamopw = team['OPW'].sum()
teamsal = team['salary'].sum()
teamplayers = team['playerID'].tolist()

teamdic = {'Salary':teamsal, 'OPW':teamopw, 'Players':teamplayers}
teamdist.append(teamdic)
```

The output I'm looking for is something like this:

```
teamdist = [{'Salary':4900000, 'OPW':78.452, 'Players':[bondsba01, etc, etc]}]
```

But for some reason all the sum actions like `teamopw = team['OPW'].sum()` do not work how I'd like, and just returns the elements in `team['OPW']`

```
print(teamopw)
0.17118131814601256
38.10700006434629
1.5699939126695253
32.9068837019903
16.990760776263674
18.22428871113601
13.447706356730897
```

Any advice on how to get this working? Thanks!

Edit: Working solution as follows. Not sure if it is the most pythonic way, but it works.

```
teamdist = []
team = pd.concat([df.sample(n=1) for df in dfposlist])

teamopw = team[['OPW']].values.sum()
teamsal = team[['salary']].values.sum()
teamplayers = team['playerID'].tolist()

teamdic = {'Salary':teamsal, 'OPW':teamopw, 'Players':teamplayers}
teamdist.append(teamdic)
```

Comment: I can't recreate issue. Are all iterations like that? Check at what point you are printing. Is there another operation you run with that series? And why concatenate one record of one dataframe or is your indentation off in post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here (with random data):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dfposlist = dict(zip(range(10),
                     [pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 5),
                                   columns=list('abcde'))
                     for i in range(10)]))
for df in dfposlist.values():
    df['f'] = list('qrstuvwxyz')

teamdist = []
team = pd.concat([df.sample(n=1) for df in dfposlist.values()])
print(team.info())

teamdic = team[['a', 'c', 'e']].sum().to_dict()
teamdic['f'] = team['f'].tolist()
teamdist.append(teamdic)
print(teamdist)

# Output:
## team.info():
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 1 to 6
Data columns (total 6 columns):
a    10 non-null float64
b    10 non-null float64
c    10 non-null float64
d    10 non-null float64
e    10 non-null float64
f    10 non-null object
dtypes: float64(5), object(1)
memory usage: 560.0+ bytes
None

## teamdist:
[{'a': -3.5380097363724601,
  'c': 2.0951152809401776,
  'e': 3.1439230427971863,
  'f': ['r', 'w', 'z', 'v', 'x', 'q', 't', 'q', 'v', 'w']}]
```

Comment: How would you deal with strings? Say, if header `b` was strings, and the desired output is `'b':[strA, strB, strC, etc]`

Comment: You wanted a sum on numeric values in the question. With strings, it is a different question and I recommend you ask it, with details, to get answers for string manipulation. The only thing I am in a position to tell you is you'll have to collapse the string column somehow, like convert them to list, or concatenate. If you tell me how you want your strings manipulated, and it still falls in the scope of your question, I can edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I would like the all the strings in the column to be returned as a list. Using some of the data from your example, the output goal is `teamdist = [{'a': 3.002, 'c':1.504, 'f':[w, x, y, z]}]`

Comment: I found a solution, not sure if it is the most efficient one.

Comment: `teamdist = []
team = pd.concat([df.sample(n=1) for df in dfposlist])


teamopw = team[['OPW']].values.sum()
teamsal = team[['salary']].values.sum()
teamplayers = team['playerID'].tolist()
teamdic = {'Salary':teamsal, 'OPW':teamopw, 'Players':teamplayers}
teamdist.append(teamdic)
print(teamdist)`

Comment: But why do you need `.values.sum` when `.sum` will just work on its own? You are just wasting resources in unnecessary conversion... Adapt from my answer, just change the column names as you need.

Comment: When I did just `.sum`, it returned the column header along with the values.